# How do I implement this event to update a textbox on another form?

Tags: c#, events, textbox, listbox

Form1 has a textbox and a button, the button opens form2. On form2 is a listbox linked to the textbox. When I type in the textbox and press enter it's text content is added to the listbox on form2. I want to click on an item in the listbox on form2 and have the text in the textbox on form1 change to the text I have selected in the listbox.
I need to use an event to do so, but there comes a point where I don't understand what to do next.

Here is the eventargs class I made:

```
// this event argument will contain the string clicked
// in the history listbox
public class ListBoxIndexChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly string _clickedText = "";

    public string ClickedText { get; }

    public ListBoxIndexChangedEventArgs(string str)
    {
        this._clickedText = str;
    }
}
```

Inside my form2 class (where the event will be raised) I declared my event:

```
public event EventHandler<ListBoxIndexChangedEventArgs> ListBoxIndexChanged;
```

This method raises the event, it's in form2's class since it's called from form2:

```
protected virtual void OnListBoxIndexChanged(ListBoxIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBoxIndexChanged != null)
        {
            ListBoxIndexChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
```

Then in the listbox's SelectedIndexChanged event on form2 I added:

```
OnListBoxIndexChanged(new ListBoxIndexChangedEventArgs(lstbHistory.Text));
```

I can't figure out what to do next though, I know I'm supposed to open the first form in a particular way so it listens for the event, but I just can't get my head around it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
thanks

Comment: Well you already figured out crucial parts. The only thing remains is after you created form2, and before you show it, add an event handler like : `form2.ListBoxIndexChanged += (s,e)=> { // do sth with e.ClickedText}`;

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because nothing happens when I include your code.

Comment: `public ListBoxIndexChangedEventArgs(string str)  { this.ClickedText = str; }` ...  `protected virtual void OnListBoxIndexChanged(ListBoxIndexChangedEventArgs e) { ListBoxIndexChanged?.Invoke(this, e); }`. You could just use DataBindings, though.

Comment: The textbox is the datasource of the listbox, how would I use it for also clicking on the listbox and sending it to the textbox?